# How can I hide form1 while Application.Run(form1) is executing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I have a form1 that I run with `Application.Run`.

I want to hide this form (I need it hidden because I run some things in the background, so they must execute) and open another form for a log-in.

The way I am trying this is by executing in my form1 constructor the command `this.Hide();` and if log in is successful, show my form1, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `this.Hide()` work for me, we need a code sample reproducing the problem...

Comment: i don't know what code to give you . it's a standard Application.Run(form) executed in Program.cs and in form's constructor there is a this.Hide()

Comment: are you executing your background stuff in form1's constructor itself (maybe before calling this.Hide()?)

Comment: i am executing my background stuff in another thread that sends to my form1 data .

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Hide new Form at start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952687/c-hide-new-form-at-start)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just override the OnVisibleChanged method and change the visibility of the form in there, something like this:

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

And that's it! Simple and clean.

Comment: I am using this right now, and it work perfect, but I cant find the running app if i want to open it? I see its running in task manager when I use you're method. but cant find where it is running tho..

Answer (score 2):

See this : [Use the ApplicationContext Class to Fully Encapsulate Splash Screen Functionality](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/applicationcontextsplash.aspx)

Its basically talks about how you would show a splash form first, then when you've finished loading, how to call your main form. (If you hide the main form while doing something in the background, do consider a splash screen)

> Quote from Introduction: *This isn't an example on how to create
>   a splash screen for your app. This
>   article explains a clean way to
>   encapsulate splash screen
>   functionality into an inherited
>   ApplicationContext class. This article
>   also shows in detail what happens
>   behind the scenes when a WinForm app
>   starts.*

Answer (score 2):

You can override [SetVisibleCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setvisiblecore.aspx) in your Form1 class, to have the Form1 instance hidden on startup. So here is an example which will hide and keep the form hidden, of course you should add some logic that will decide when the form should actually be allowed to become visible.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
  public Form1() 
  { 
    InitializeComponent(); 
  } 

  protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) 
  {       
    // Quick and dirty to keep the main window invisible
    // you can put some logic here to decide when to use the
    // incomming value and when to force it to be false as I 
    // am showing here.       
    base.SetVisibleCore(false); 
  } 
}
```

Here is a simple example albeit contrived. Form1 starts invisible and shows Form2, when Form2 is closed it allows Form1 to become visible and shows the form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HideMainWinForm
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    // Initially the main form cannot show
    private bool _canShow = false; 

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      Form2 frm = new Form2();
      frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm_FormClosed);
      frm.Show();      
    }

    void frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
      // Once Form2 is closed we now allow the main form to
      // become visible.
      _canShow = true;
      this.Show();
    }

    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
    {
      base.SetVisibleCore(_canShow && value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Badescu Alexandru, what is it that does not work? Does the form no hide? Can you share how you tried this?

Comment: public Form1(){ InitializeComponent();
            SetVisibleCore(false);
            logIn li = new logIn(this);
            li.Show();


            



        }

Comment: i've used your function except that instead of "false" at base.SetVisibleCore(false) i've included the bool "value"

Comment: @Badescu Alexandru, you should not be calling SetVisibleCore, the Framework will call it. You only provide the visiblity logic in the function. See my simplistic updated example.

Comment: If you use the code in the second example in a new test application, does that do what you expect?

Comment: It's the right idea but the Handle won't be created.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952687/c-hide-new-form-at-start/1953721#1953721

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some background work before you show your form, I would suggest two possible options.

The first one, is to simply do your background work *before* you create the form and call `Application.Run` on it.

The second option, if you need a message loop to be active while you do the background work, is to use the `Application.Run` overload that doesn't take a From as a parameter, and later show your Form exactly when you want to. The only catch is that you will have to cal `Application.Exit` or `Application.ExitThread` manually when you want to end the application (because it won't have a Form whose Close event it can watch).

So your code could look something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    // trigger some background work
    ...

    // and start the message pump
    Application.Run();
}


void SomeBackgroundWork()
{
    // let's say now you completed the background work and you want to show your main Form
    MyForm f = new MyForm();
    f.Close += delegate { Application.Exit(); };
    f.Show();
}
```

Please comment if some clarification is needed...

Comment: The thing is that i am sending data to my form from a thread so i can never exit it , so the first option goes out of order (because there is a stream that is continuous so my program recieves data very often and the second option isn't a valid one because i will require the form to go multiple times to "hidden mode" because a user can log on and off as many times as he want .. and closing the app and restarting it isn't an option

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

by calling `this.Hide()` in the constructor you actually set `this.Visible = false`, but immediately after the form instantiation, form.Show is called (by `Application.Run`) and `form.Show` internally set `this.Visible = true` (well, of course is the opposite of Hide...).

You could do in this way:

```
private bool firstShow = true;

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstShow)
    {
        this.Hide();
        firstShow = false;
        return;
    }
    base.OnShown(e);
}
```

The form will appear for a moment, and then will disappear immediately.

The boolean flag `firstShow` allows you to hide the form only for the first call of `Show()` while for the following invocations it will work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms have an event that works perfectly for this called `Form.Shown`. It is called only once per Form object when the Form is first shown. Basically it's digEmAll's answer, but already built in.

Add an event handler to the constructor that is called by `Form1.Shown` then in the hanlder called `Hide()`

```
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent()
    this.Shown += new EventHandler(form1_Shown);
    // call splash page
}

void form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this way.  However, you must have attention in methods that use await and async.

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e){
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

Methods that use (await and async) must have the word (result) in the form initialization.

Example:

```
public frmForm1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    try {
        if (Program.LaunchedViaStartup == true) {
            var varclsReturnBack = funcStartBackGroundObjectsAsync().Result;
        }
    } catch (Exception varException) {
        Console.Write(varException.Message);
    }
}
```